# Border-collapse not removing table header cells borders

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I have a table (for tabular data, not for layout), and I want no borders to be visible in the table header. As far as I know, the way to do it is to specify `border-collaps: collapse;` in the CSS. However, borders were still visible after this in my case.

I searched this site, tried the various solutions that have been suggested here (e.g. `border-spacing: 0px`, `display: none`) but nothing worked. The borders are still there.

The code in my CSS now looks like this:

```css
.tableStyle2 {
    border-spacing: 0px;
}

.tableStyle2 th {
    background-color: #1B7AE0;
    border-color: #1B7AE0;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}

.tableStyle2 tr {
    display: none;
}
```

and the corresponding HTML code is as follows:

```
<table class = "tableStyle2" width = "100%">
<tr>
<th> ... </th>
<th> ... </th>
<th> ... </th>
<th> ... </th>
<th> ... </th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Any idea of what is causing this, and how is it possible to hide the borders between cells in the table header?

Comment: Post more of your actual code, or even better, post a fiddle. I tried a fiddle using the code you've shown, and I don't see any borders, so there must be something hidden in the details.

Comment: The title of the question is misleading. The `border-collapse` property does work, it just does not do what it was incorrectly expected to do (remove borders).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each of the `<td>`s determines (and is responsible for) its own border.

```css
.tableStyle2 {
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;  /* <--- add this so all the internal <td>s share adjacent borders  */
    border: 1px solid black;  /* <--- so the outside of the <th> don't get missed  */
}

.tableStyle2 th {
    background-color: #1B7AE0;
    border-color: #1B7AE0;
    border-spacing: 0px;  /* <---- won't really need this if you have border-collapse = collapse */
    border-style: none;   /* <--- add this for no borders in the <th>s  */
}

.tableStyle2 tr {
   /* display: none; <--- you want to show the table  */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, and for some reason it no longer shows the background color, so it's hard to tell if there are borders anymore. Do <th>s determine their borders, like <td>s? Should I use the <thead> tag instead of <tr> in the table header? Could this have anything to do with the border-collapse not working?

Comment: I finally got the borders to disappear! I put "border-collapse: collapse;" under tableStyle2 and "border-style: none;" under tableStyle2 th. In other words, not fundamentally different from what you've suggested, and, while I got the table to look the way I wanted it to, I'm still not sure why it didn't work the first few times. Thank you, though.

Comment: I found that this solution, setting `border-collapse` on the `th`'s themselves rather than just the table, was necessary for desktop Safari.